# An easy-to-read and engaging book to learn supply chain modelling problems

Tags: supply-chain, books

I recently came across a book on Abstract Algebra by Charles Pinter. I am surprised by its simplicity to explain the concepts.

I am very interested in OR problems in supply chain management. I can imagine that there are a lot of OR problems at every stage of the supply chain, e.g., inventory management, order fulfilment, pricing, matching, etc. I am wondering if there are books that can help me learn supply chain management and mathematical formulation of these problems.

Answer (score 1):

A really good choice could be ["Supply Chain Engineering: Models and Applications" by Ravindran and  Warsing](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=5WrSBQAAQBAJ). It covers most of the Supply Chain related problems and, having some knowledge of Operations Research, it is easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find out many useful materials just by searching the community (OR.SE) and some of them would be:

- [Recommended books/materials for practical applications of Operations Research in industry](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/117/recommended-books-materials-for-practical-applications-of-operations-research-in/196#196)
- [Supply Chain Public Data Repository](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/529/supply-chain-public-data-repository)
- [Real-world examples of supply chain contracts?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/430/real-world-examples-of-supply-chain-contracts)
- [Recommendations for OM blogs](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5885/recommendations-for-om-blogs)
- [Case Studies and Real Problems for Teaching Optimization and Modelling](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/case-studies-and-real-problems-for-teaching-optimization-and-modelling/1454#1454)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Fundamentals of Supply Chain Theory](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/sctheory/)